# Can you make it so when the user clicks anywhere inside of an iframe it redirects them to the source url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

So I would like to know if its possible to redirect and open a users tab to the source url's page that the iframe tag is using when they click anywhere inside of the iframe. So instead of them being able to browse the iframe I would like it to automatically open the new tab with the src's url in it.

Here is the code I am working with currently.

```
<!-- CSS -->

<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">        

    <style>
        body {
    color: purple;
    background-color: #663300 }
    </style>

    <script>
function virtualSubmit(form){
    var text = form.searchtext.value;
    var targets = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
        items = targets.length;

    for(var i = 0; i<items; i++){
        var target = targets[i],
            url = target.getAttribute('data-url');
        target.src = url + text;
    }

    return false;
}
    </script>

    <body>

        <!--The Search bar as well-->
<form onsubmit="return virtualSubmit(this)";>
    <input name="searchtext" type="text" />
    <input type="image" src="Searchbutton.png" alt="Search Button" height="20" width="20"/>
</form>

    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/custom"
            data-url="http://www.google.com/custom?q="
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250"></iframe>

    <iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki"
            data-url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250"></iframe>


    <iframe src="http://m.dictionary.com/definition"
            data-url="http://m.dictionary.com/definition/"
            width="250"
            height="600" onmouseover="width=400" onmouseout="width=250"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the iframe is a separate domain, you cannot modify the iframe directly.  The browser will prevent it because of same-origin protections.

But, depending upon your exact layout, you can sometimes put a transparent div over the top of the iframe (using absolute positioning and z-index), set up event handlers for that div and intercept any click events that the user intended for the iframe and if your desire is to redirect the browser page to somewhere else, you can do that upon one of those clicks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("iframe").each(function() {
        var iframe = $(this);
        var pos = iframe.position();
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var s = div.style;
        s.position = "absolute";
        s.left = pos.left + "px";
        s.top = pos.top + "px";
        s.height = iframe.height() + "px";
        s.width = iframe.width() + "px";
        iframe.parent().append(div);
        $(div).data("src", iframe.attr("src")).click(function() {
            window.location = $(this).data("src");
        });
    });
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EB2kh/

I removed the dynamically sizing from the iframes because that complicates the problem for the purposes of showing you the concept, but if you really wanted it to work with that, you could move/resize the divs anytime the iframes were moved/resized.

Comment: Could I have an example for an idea of what the div would look like? or at least how hard would it be to match the div's src url with the one inside the iframe as im using javascript to load what is in the textbar into a query search?

Comment: Although this takes it from the source you see with the java script I had previously it went to the search of what you type in the box, inside of the iframe how would i make it redirect to that url?

Comment: @Ibounes - If you want to go to the `data-url` location, than change `iframe.attr("src")` to `iframe.data("url")` in my script.  You really ought to attempt to understand each line of this script and then it should be easier to understand how to modify to suit your tastes more precisely.  We want to get you started in the right direction, but then let you modify it yourself going forward.

Comment: Good point, Ill try to examine the code more before I make any further comments. Anyways thanks for the help!

Comment: I have try'd your advice though and it still isn't working, but this time the div isn't showing up at all. I'm thinking it involves the previous javascript code above it.

Comment: @Ibounes - there's not much I can do to help without seeing the exact code you're trying.  Did you check the browser error console of debugger console to see if you have script errors?  That should be the first place you look when a script isn't working.  Google those if you don't know how to look there.

Comment: @Ibounes - I said to change it to `iframe.data("url")`.  That's not what you did - you have `iframe.attr("url")`.  Please look at my code recommendation more carefully (5th comment down on this answer).

Comment: Yeah i'm almost positive that there is something conflicting between my previous javascript code and yours but i can seem to identify the problem...